# MS Project 2010 - extracting data into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ms-project, ms-project-server-2010

We have several MS projects being used and a system written in SQL Server by us. Would MS Project Server allow us to set up something like SSIS procs to continuously get data from the MS Project databases and insert them into our SQL Server database?

Is there a way to link all systems or a better way to do this where we're not paying a monthly fee for MS Project Server? Would actually like to bypass MS Project Server if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can write a vba routine which sends the schedule data up to a database. I've done this previously sending schedule data up to SQL server using ODBC.

You'd need to decide what data you want to see - getting task, resource and assignment data is quite straightforward, but if you need to look at time phased data that can slow things down. Then it's just a case of looping through the collections and using a SQL INSERT statement to squirt each task, assignment or resource up into the tables.

If that's all project server was being used for, then you can retire it and its supporting infrastructure. Additionally, you would then only need Project Standard client, which is about half the price of the Project Professional client.

Comment: ODBC is not enabled for MS Project 2007 and later.

Comment: Not via the UI, but it is still available from within the VBA code, which is what I've proposed.